# How to integrate a music player in iOS system

Tags: ios, media-player

How can I integrate a music app in the iOS system that my own custom player can handle actions  (play, pause, forward) from the unlock screen and how to integrate that is displayed as player app in the double-click-home-button menu like on this screenshot Spotify does:[image]

**EDIT:** The application itself is based at the [Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html), but in this documents there isn't any hint how to get the custom player in this 'double-click-home-button' menu.

Comment: Please show what you currently have and are working on. We love to help people, but we aren't a development team that works for you :)

Comment: Of course, I do not want to develop it for me. ;) I just need a hint what to do to get the app in the double-click-home-button menu. At the moment I am having a player app which uses the MPMusicPlayerController (and some more things from the Media Player Framework of iOS). The problem is I can not find any note in the Media Player Framework Reference how to integrate the application in this menu.

Comment: My suggestion use HTML5 player which support all new Mobile Devices and do some coding in Javascript for working play pause and many feature and for having same look use CSS as I also work on same thing made a beautiful video player but unfortunately the site had been shutdown due to getting less revenue from it.But it work beautiful in all mobile and touch devices

Comment: @mihohl: Dustin's comment is still relevant. Please provide a description of what you tried, what documentation you read, and what search terms you used. If you did none of those things before posting, you're expecting too much of others.

Comment: Folks downvoting this question: you should explain why you're downvoting it. It's a legitimate question and it may not be clear to the original poster why you don't like it.

Comment: I think it's clear from the comments so far, Jonathan. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register your application for remote control events, and if you start playing either audio or video, your application will automatically take over these controls. See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html) for more info. This API is available on iOS 4 and later.

To set the string below the controls ("The Butterfly Defect" in your screenshot), use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, available on iOS 5 and later.

Comment: Thanks, the link to reference was exactly what I was looking for. You helped me a lot! (:

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for exactly this same thing.  Thanks.

Comment: Link is broken, please repair that!

Comment: Please update the link, it's merely for the UIKit doc and not helpful.